# Javascript function not being called from QWebFrame/QWebView

Tags: javascript, qt

Can someone please explain why my JavaScript function is not being called.

The JS function is:

```
function loadKMLFile(kmlUrl)
{
    alert('in loadKMLFile().');
    google.earth.fetchKml(ge, kmlUrl, finishFetchKml);
}
```

My C++ Qt code is:

```
void MainWindow::on_loadKML_button_clicked()
{
    QString fileUrl = ui->textEdit->toPlainText(); // Get path to file
    ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("loadKMLFile(" + fileUrl + ")");
}
```

When I run my app, I enter in a path to a file to load. This is then extracted by the C++ method above and a call made via evaluateJavaScript passing in the path.

If the path passed in is empty string, the JS function is called and the alert box appears. If a put a single character (let alone the whole path) in the text edit, the function is not called I do not get the alert box appear.

Any ideas would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

did you enable javascript already?

```
webView->page()->settings()->testAttribute( QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled );
```

refer:[qwebsettings WebAttribute](http://doc.qt.digia.com/snapshot/qwebsettings.html#WebAttribute-enum)

Comment: I managed to solve this one myself. Bit of a school boy error. Needed to add some missing single quotes so that javascript interpreted the parameters correctly as below:

    ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("loadKMLFile('" + fileUrl + "')");